# iOS guided access keyboard bug

Tags: ios, keyboard, titanium, guided-access

I'm development an app through titanium. When I was running it on actual iPad, I got a bug that keyboard cannot close if guided access was enabled.

Scenario:

- Guided Access is on in settings
- Focus on a TextField, keyboard shows up
- Triple click on home button, start Guided Access. (With Password). Note, the keyboard is still up for textfield.
- Click "Resume" button, return back to app.
- Now, if you try to dismiss keyboard, it just stuck there. And keyboard no response until next TextField or TextArea.

And this always happens. I'm not sure if this is a bug from Titanium or iOS itself. I'm trying to replicate by native objective c code.

Does anyone have clue how to fix this?

Thanks

UPDATES:

1. I've tried to replicate by native SDK. Nothing happened. So I guess this is a bug only for Titanium.
2. Finally address the problem, when you open the number pad for guided access then go back to app, it will cause the textfield lose focus. So, if user tap/click the textField, then there will be no problem.
3. And there is another scenario: There are two window, A and B. B has a textField, and I've set it focus when it opened. In Window A, I triple click home button and open the number pad to enter password. Go back to app, open window B. Now since I've programmatically focus the textfield, so nobody click the textField. Now if you try to dismiss the keyboard without touch/click the textfield, you will see the same bug happened before. While if you click the textField, manually re-focus it, there will be no problem.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, indeed. Could you file a Jira ticket with this info? https://jira.appcelerator.org/

Comment: I've seen a very similar same behaviour with a simple HTML5/Javascript web app. Open the app, click on a `textarea` and the keyboard appears as expected.
Dismiss the keyboard and turn Guided Access on, click on a `textarea` and the keyboard refuses to appear. 
I can see the focus event being fired on the `textarea` and the caret appears but no keyboard.